# Adding elements in a ScrollViewer.

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to create a method that would be able to add elements in a Scroll Viewer.
What I did in the XAML page is this

```
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel Name="ContentControl">
            <Canvas Name="canvas1" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <TextBlock Name="time" Text="{Binding Record.RecordedTime}" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="7" Width="370"  FontSize="36"/>
                <Button Name="save" Canvas.Left="380" Height="58" Canvas.Top="6" />                
            </Canvas>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

But I don't know what should I use in the code behind. Well I tried something which I know is wrong, but anyway here it is:

```
public void Add()
{
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.DataContext = canvas1.DataContext;
    ContentControl.Children.Add(canvas);
}
```

So can anyone show me how to write this add method?
Thank you.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're trying to add a copy of `canvas1`, with the same controls inside? If so, you should use an `ItemsControl`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: are you trying to add another copy of that canvas1?  the code you have in Add right now should work, its just that your new Canvas doesn't have any children, so you've just added a blank empty canvas under the existing canvas1.  something like snoop would show you that.  Are you trying to have multiple items?  then you might want to look into `ItemsControl` and `DataTemplate`?

Comment: Yes I want multiple copies of the canvas with diferrent text in the textblock, and also one under the other, just like a ListBox add method.

Comment: you can use the listbox control directly right? scrollviewer is there by default.